# Javascript .children is giving incorrect results on YouTube

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a TamperMonkey script running on YouTube. When I inspect the page and look at child nodes, I see different nodes to those that are returned with the .children property.

This issue seems to only affect Firefox - Chrome and Edge give the expected result on the .children property.

[image: Screenshot of console results]

---

In the console I run `document.getElementById( "masthead" )`

In the inspector there are then 5 child nodes - an "iron-media-query" element, and 4 div elements with IDs: ticker, interstitial, background, container.

Expanding the returned value in the console agrees with this.

---

Then I run `document.getElementById( "masthead" ).children`

This gives 5 completely different child nodes - a svg element, and 4 div elements with IDs: search-container, search-input, masthead-logo, masthead-skeleton-icons.

---

Why am I getting a different result when calling .children to when I explore a node and look at its children?

How do I access the actual children, as shown in the inspector?

Comment: As it's a live HTMLCollection, you can try howering the mouse cursor over the items and they will be highlighted. At least in Chrome. Where I can't reproduce the issue, by the way.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue only appears in Firefox - Chrome & Edge work perfectly. Interestingly, Chrome/Edge return the children as a HTMLCollection, but Firefox returns its results as an Array.